# "768 worker_connections are not enough" error after a fresh installation of nginx and ROR

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ruby-on-rails, thin

I have a fresh installation of nginx and ruby on rails. But it gives me a '500 Internal Server Error' while testing.

The error.log for my app has the following:

```
2014/05/01 17:27:15 [alert] 1423#0: *6892 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 24.15.27.113, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://24.15.27.113:80/", host: "myapp"
2014/05/01 17:27:16 [alert] 1423#0: *7656 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 24.15.27.113, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://24.15.27.113:80/favicon.ico", host: "myapp"
2014/05/01 17:45:50 [alert] 1453#0: *766 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 24.15.27.113, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://24.15.27.113:80/", host: "myapp"
2014/05/01 17:45:50 [alert] 1453#0: *1530 768 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 24.15.27.113, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://24.15.27.113:80/favicon.ico", host: "myapp"
```

The nginx.conf has the following:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

myapp.example.com config file:

```
upstream myapp {
  #server 24.15.27.113;
  #server 24.15.27.113:3001;
  #server 24.15.27.113:3002;
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
  #server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name .example.com;

  access_log /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/access.log;
  error_log  /var/www/myapp.example.com/log/error.log;
  root     /var/www/myapp.example.com;
  index    index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    try_files /system/maintenance.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @ruby;
  }

  location @ruby {
    proxy_pass http://myapp;
  }
}
```

After switching back to use ip 127.0.0.1:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3001 inside upstream block, the server generated the errors:

```
2014/05/05 10:34:39 [error] 6158#0: *2 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 52.74.130.210, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001”, host: "24.15.27.113"

2014/05/05 10:34:39 [error] 6158#0: *2 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 52.74.130.210, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "24.15.27.113"

2014/05/05 10:34:39 [error] 6158#0: *2 no live upstreams while connecting to upstream, client: 52.74.130.210, server: example.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://myapp/favicon.ico", host: "24.15.27.113"
```

Update 05/05/2014:
I ran the following command to check the connection:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 3000
```

and the result was:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I tried to restart the thin server, but got error messages.

```
thin restart -C /etc/thin/myapp.example.com -o 3000
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:129:in `send_signal': Can't stop process, no PID found in tmp/pids/thin.3000.pid (Thin::PidFileNotFound)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/daemonizing.rb:111:in `kill'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:94:in `block in stop'
```

Comment: What is your full nginx configuration? How much traffic do you have to the server?

Comment: I added with the full nginx configuration. There's zero traffic as it is a new server with a new ip. The page error appeared right after I restarted nginx.

Comment: And the vhost configuration?

Comment: I updated the original post. I tried with multiple ips and ports. But the results were the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `proxy_set_header` and `proxy_redirect` directives should be in `location @ruby` block.

For `upstream` block, you should use `localhost` and the actual port of your Ruby server. Without port, the upstream would connect to this nginx server instance, which is a loop.

Comment: I updated the @ruby block and the upstream block, but now I received 111: Connection refused error. I added them into the original post. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure your upstream ROR server is running and reachable on ports 3000 / 3001 on the server? You can use `telnet 127.0.0.1 3000` on the server to check this.

Comment: I used telnet and the connections were refused. I tried restart the thin server but got new error messages. I updated the original post.

Comment: You should check on your ROR configuration closely. I am not familiar with that though.

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but i had the same issue and the accepted answer didnt work for me.

I had to increase the number of [worker_connections](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections), as stated [here](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/157416#693442).

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
events {
    worker_connections 20000;
}
```